# Hibernate inheritance - no field annotated with Id

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, h2

I've been doing some reading on hibernate inheritance and am having trouble applying it to my situation. [I tried doing what this post mentioned which seems like it should be what I want.](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-inheritance-table-per-subclass-annotation-xml-mapping/)

Here are the 3 classes I'm working with - each should have its own table:

- ParentClass

  - ChildClass
- SeparateTable

Below is essentially what I have laid out. However, when I try to run my tests on the Child class service, they all fail for `java.lang.IllegalStateException: no field annotated with Id`. Now if I'm understanding that article/blog post correctly, I shouldn't need need the `ChildClass` annotated with `Id` since it should be picked up in the parent class.

I could be completely wrong as I'm new to Hibernate, but if you guys have any thoughts, I'd be glad to hear what I'm doing wrong.

**ParentClass**

```
@Table(name="parent_class")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class ParentClass {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long m_id;

@Column(nullable=false, length=2500)
private String m_variable;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="s_key", nullable=false)
private SeparateTable m_sTable;

etc...
}
```

**ChildClass**

```
@Table(name="child_class")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="m_id")
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {

@Column(nullable=false, length=100)
private String m_name;

@Column(nullable=true, length=250)
private String m_description;

etc...
}
```

**SeparateTable**

```
@Table(name="separate_table")
public class SeparateTable {

@Id
@Column(unique=true, nullable=false, length=100)
private String m_user;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="m_sTable", cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval=true)
private Set<ParentClass> m_parents;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="m_sTable", cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval=true, targetEntity=ParentClass.class)
private Set<ChildClass> m_children;

etc...
}
```

Comment: I guess you just omitted the `@javax.persistence.Entity` annotations?

Comment: This may not fix your problem but ParentClass should be abstract, especially if you don't want to create entities with that class. This parent class should then be annotated with `@MappedSuperclass`. Hibernate has sometimes problems obtaining the correct entity type from proxy objects if the parent class is a regular entity. I guess there are some SO questions out there mentioning that problem.

Comment: @Wolfram - When both of these classes were separated out (had duplicate variables in each class) all I needed was `@Table` and I had no issues. So to answer your question, I have never used the `@javax.persistence.Entity` annotation.

Comment: @Tom - I've seen `@MappedSuperclass` used before but I wasn't 100% when it's applicable to use. I do want to create entities with the parent class as well as the child class.  Edit: I take that back, Tom. After reading the documentation, I read: `A mapped superclass has no separate table defined for it.` That would suggest that it would not be applicable in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Change the scope of `m_id` to `protected`

```
protected Long m_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that a util class of ours was looking for the Id field for every class that extended an abstract Hibernate class. Since the child class had no `@Id` annotation, it was blowing up.

All that was needed was to add a simple check to see if there was a parent class and if so, get the annotated field from there.